# How to workaround null objects in Java?

Tags: java, null

I am currently working on a program which has a method which computes the average of a course which contains five students. My question is what to do to the average method so that it ignores any student object which has not been created? Here s1, s2,s3,s4 and s5 are 5 objects of type 'student'. So how to write the formula so that it ignores any student which has a null value because it has not been added? To be more specific I want to edit the "else" part. My code is below-

```
public double average()
{
    if (s1 != null && s2 != null && s3 != null && s4 != null && s5 != null)
    {
        avg = (double) (s1.average() + s2.average() + s3.average() + s4.average() + s5.average())/ counter;     
        return avg;
    }
    else
    {
        avg = 0;
        return avg;
    }
 }
```

Comment: In this case the solution is simple: don't write such if statements. Generalise. It looks like you want a list/array/collection. Let the program do the work for you, more or less. Don't manually code all possible situations.

Comment: @keyser is there any way to make this method without using arrays as I have not learned them yet. I dont mind the effort of writing all the type of situations, but if someone could just tell me for even one...

Comment: Yes there is, but you're not doing yourself any favors by putting off learning about them. You can add x.average() to a total and keep track of the number of non-nulls along the way, e.g. `if (s1 != null) total += s1.average(); numStudents++;` That way you get 5 if statements, 1 per student. Note that I don't recommend ever writing such code :p

Comment: @keyser I just started coding so I haven't reached that chapter yet  :P but could you explain more about how to keep track of non-nulls? Also what does this total mean? will it be used in the average formula?

Comment: Keep track as in `numStudents++` for each non-null you encounter, inside that `if` and then `total/numStudents` at the end. Very manual. Like this: "if this student exists, add to total, add to count", after 5 checks: "divide total by number of students counted, return avg"

Answer (score 0):

First, your method doesn't seem to take any parameters. I think it should. I would suggest you write a [variadac function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) like

```
public static double average(Student... students) {
    if (students == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    double value = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (Student s : students) {
        if (s != null) {
            value += s.average();
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return value / count;
}
```

If you must use your `s1` - `s5` then you could use [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) like

```
public double average() {
    double value = 0;
    int count = 0;
    if (s1 != null) {
        value += s1.average();
        count++;
    }
    if (s2 != null) {
        value += s2.average();
        count++;
    }
    if (s3 != null) {
        value += s3.average();
        count++;
    }
    if (s4 != null) {
        value += s4.average();
        count++;
    }
    if (s5 != null) {
        value += s5.average();
        count++;
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return value / count;
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't this use the formula even if there is 1 or 2 null objects because the counter would technically be more than 0?

Comment: @ScaVenGerS - You might want to rephrase that comment.  It makes no sense to me.

Comment: @StephenC I was asking that supposing that s4 and s5 are null, then what will this code do. Will it skip those objects and ignore them in the formula at the end?

Comment: @ScaVenGerS Yes. It would skip them, and at the end they wouldn't be included in the count.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch thank you! I have tried it and it works :D

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `List<Student>` (a `List` collection which contains objects of type `Student`) and then change the code within your method to the following:

```
int sampleSum = 0, sampleQuantity = 0;
for(Student student : studentList) {
    if (student == null) {
        // This student object is not set, so skip to the next object in studentList
        continue;
    }
    sampleSum += student.average;
    ++sampleQuantity;
}
return sampleSum / sampleQuantity;
```

Note that this will throw an exception if none of the students in `studentList` are non-null, because a divide-by-zero will occur. You might prefer to modify the code to behave differently if `sampleQuantity` is still zero at the point just before the return statement.

So far as creating a `List<Student>` that's very easy:

```
List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
studentList.add(anyStudentObject);
```

It's definitely worth reading about [the Java Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) because they are an excellent component of Java.

Also read about [the for-each loop in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) because that's a very tidy way of iterating through an `Iterable` type such as a `List`.

Comment: Why would there be null Students in the list in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for the help and I have started reading on arrays, but for this homework our professor had specifically told us to not use arrays as we had not done them before this project. Although I really appreciate the help to see another way of creating this method :D

Comment: @EJP I just want to give the users some freedom to add less than 5 students if they want to.

Comment: @ScaVenGerS - You have missed EJP's point.  Why would you **add** nulls to the list?

Comment: @StephenC I actually am not using the list to create the method because my professor has restricted me to do so. That's why I have to check manually for a null and then decide what the average formula would be.

Comment: @ScaVenGerS - I put it to you that you have *probably* misinterpreted what your professor told you to do vis-a-vis arrays.  Alternatively, you are trying to make your program more general than you are required to do ... and more general that it is wise to do without using arrays of collections.

Comment: @StephenC That is true actually because I am supposed to add all 5 student objects but I was just curious how I can create the program without some students. I am not actually going to implement this in my homework.

Comment: @ScaVenGerS - Well we've given you the answer.  Use arrays or lists.  The fact that your teacher has said don't is not relevant ... because you are no longer talking about the problem he/she has told you to solve.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before it's better to use arrays or similar, but here's a solution anyway:

```
public double average() {
    double avg = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    if (s1 != null) {
        avg += s1.average();
        counter++;
    }

    // ...

    if (s5 != null) {
        avg += s5.average();
        counter++;
    }

    if (counter > 0) return avg / counter;
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in your code. I think your final if block should contain `avg += s5.average()` instead of `s1`.